# WPF CollectionList to ListCollectionView from datagrid itemsource

Tags: wpfdatagrid

I am new to WPF and can't understand why this error is hapoening.

My code:

```
List<ReConfigureBeneDiagProcCloneGroup> P = new List<ReConfigureBeneDiagProcCloneGroup>();
P = (List<ReConfigureBeneDiagProcCloneGroup>)ReviewItemsGrid.ItemsSource;
```

In the second line of code, im getting the below error.

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[iConfig.Common.Entities.ReConfigure.ReConfigureBeneDiagProcCloneGroup]'
```

Comment: Please someone come forward and help me....its urgent for me.

Comment: Myself found the solution for the above error.....need to do Casting for converting Collections objects into List object. Code as shown below  " Grid.ItemsSource.Cast<ReConfigureBenfitsDiagProcClone>().ToList(); "